# org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException when integrating Ant-Contrib into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, ant-contrib

I've tried to integrate Ant-Contrib 1.0b3 into Eclipse by adding the ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar and the appendant jar-files from the libs-directory to the "Global Entries"-section of the Ant-Runtime-preferences page in Eclipse.

For tasks that don't need the libs, such as `propertyregex`, this works fine.
But when I try to use the `postMethod` task I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException
```

Any suggestions on what to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your rig doesn't include the [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) which must be a dependency of ant-contrib.

According to the dependencies [here](http://gump.zones.apache.org/gump/test/ant-contrib/ant-contrib/details.html) you might also need [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/), but you've probably already got that.

Answer (score 0):

It's much cleaner to specify classpath when you define 3rd-party tasks in your build file.
Provide either individual jars or add a `<fileset>` of dependent jars to classpath, e.g.

```
<taskdef
  resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"
  uri="http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net"
>
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="${ant-contrib.jar}"/>
    <fileset dir="${ant-contrib-dependency.lib}">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>    
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

You can define default `ant-contrib.jar` and `ant-contrib-dependency.lib` properties in this build file, and provide project specific overrides in ant build tool VM arguments.  This means you don't have to copy these files into various directories on your system.